# Sending message from telegram messenger bot to e-mail

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I just need that my telegram bot would sent a message to my e-mail. For example, my bot has a form that user need to fill out, and I just want to get results from bot to be appeared in my e-mail. The form of the bot was developed in ManyBot. I have found several results on passing e-mail message into telegram

Comment: You have to do programming stuff, not use service such as *ManyBot*.

Comment: is there any good tutorials on developing a telegram bot that you can suggest? @Sean